# iPhone safari browser API?

Tags: iphone, iphone-web-app

Please disregard the title. But my problem is related to it... ;-)

Is there a way I can embed safari browser to my iPhone app? Or some other iphone browser app that is possible.

What I'm trying to achieve actually is that on my application the user has the ability to send link/page that he/she is currently browsing, providing that the UI is the same as the iPhone browser.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Related sample code might help. You can copy Safari's UI, but I doubt they would approve that in the App Store...

Comment: You'll have to build up the UI for interacting with the `UIWebView`. I've seen a lot of interfaces that are pretty close to the standard Safari Mobile, so I doubt it would be too much of an issue.

Comment: for opening Safari browser in Iphone App just use this follg command UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 [app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

Answer (score 0):

Agree with raidfive.... Try [this](http://www.myfirstiphoneapplication.com/2010/03/iphone-in-app-web-browser/). Will definitely help you.